# What means that certain spring bean is enabled by default? How to access that bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using xml-based spring config. I found in spring doc that certain bean is enabled by default. What does it mean? And how can I address that bean to change one of it's properties. I understand, that if I define a bean, I can configure it in it's definition. But what about existing "enabled-by-default" bean?

EDIT: from org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver javadoc:

```
@Deprecated public class AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver
extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver Implementation of the
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver interface
that handles exceptions through the ExceptionHandler annotation. This
exception resolver is enabled by default in the
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
```

Comment: Post the link where u came across that phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that just specifying a `DispatcherServlet` servlet in your application configuration will register an `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` bean if you haven't specified any other `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans.

You will notice that there is a `DispatcherServlet.properties` file on your classpath when you run a Spring MVC webapp. This properties file defines, among others, this property

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver,\
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver,\
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver
```

which describes the default `HandlerExceptionResolver` classes to create beans for and register in the `DispatcherServlet's` `List<HandlerExceptionResolver>`. This is done in the `DispatcherServlet#getDefaultStrategies()` method.

Note that this only happens if the context your use to initialize the `DispatcherServlet` doesn't declare any `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans. A typical application will register different `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans with the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element or `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This is also why the class is deprecated.

Comment: I didn't find any sources how I can register a bean inside an `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element. Also I d like to know, how can I configure one of those beans (set a property) without affecting other beans. You said that if I declare `HandlerExceptionResolver` then default resolvers will be removed, why is that, is there a way to make them stay? Thanks in advance. I'm a big noob in spring so any sources or docs will be helpful.

Comment: @dhblah The configuration of `mvc:annotation-driven` is explained in the [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable). Setting a bean property of one bean doesn't affect other beans. There is no way to make the default `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans stay. The workaround is to explicitly declare beans for them yourself.

Comment: I didn't found instructions on that page. Thought I looked up through http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd and didn't found `xsd:elements` for exception or handler. Is it configured some other way?

Comment: @dhblah No there is no sub-element of `HandlerExceptionResolver` in `<mvc:annotation-driven>`. That's its actual functionality. If you want to overwrite that all you need to do is declare `<bean>` elements of some sub type of `HandlerExceptionResolver`. They will be discovered automatically in the context.

Comment: Okay thanks. Now I know how to configure it. Btw why some properties of DispatcherServlet are configured in `<mvc:annotation-driven>` while others are not?

Comment: @dhblah The `DispatcherServlet` was meant to be configured by auto-detecting beans (following some convention, type) in the context. You can do this manually (long) or use `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableWebMvc` (short). The `DispatcherServlet` stills needs to be valid even if you don't specify your beans, that's why it has defaults.